# Get user info from Active Directory based on user input

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory

I have a WPF application that allows users to login using their username and password and that is verified through Active Directory. I would like to pull their username from the textbox and populate fields with their first name, last name and email that is in active directory.

This is what I've tried:

```
try
{
    //enter AD settings 
    PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://");

    //create search user and add criteria
    string username = Email_box.Text;

    UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
    u.GivenName = Email_box.Text;

    //Search for user
    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);

    UserPrincipal result = (UserPrincipal)search.FindOne();
    search.Dispose();

    //show details in textboxes 
    Firstname_Text_Box.Text = u.GivenName;
    Lastname_Text_Box.Text = u.Surname;
}
catch (Exception d)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + d.Message);
}
```

Comment: And?  What isn't working?

Comment: the text boxes are not being populated.

Comment: should you be using result.GivenName or u.GivenName?

Comment: Have you checked the question mentioned under related section on the right? Probably you will get the answer already covered in some of the existing question.

Comment: I have tried having result.GivenName and that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Active Directory but shouldn't you be using the results to populate the text box?

So instead of this:

```
Firstname_Text_Box.Text = u.GivenName;
Lastname_Text_Box.Text = u.Surname;
```

shouldn't it be:

```
Firstname_Text_Box.Text = result.GivenName;
Lastname_Text_Box.Text = result.Surname;
```

Here is what I was looking at for an example: http://ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm

Comment: i originally had result.GivenName and that was not working either.

Comment: I would watch results and step through your code. If results is null you are not searching for a user correctly. I believe another issue is what Astx was saying. According to your code you are searching for a u.givenname with a email address. Could you also post your UserPrincipal class so we can see all of its members?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, there may also be a problem with the QueryFilter.

```
u.GivenName = Email_box.Text;
```

This implies that you are expecting the Given name to be the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing "rootDSE" in your call to:

```
 PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAP://rootDSE");
```

Or you can try with the following. Get the user's path from AD with their username. Then use the path to retrieve their information:

```
 string _Path = string.Empty;
 SearchResult results = null;

 using (var rootDse = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE"))
        {
            if (null != rootDse)
            {
                string path = string.Format("LDAP://{0}", rootDse.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0]);
                using (var de = new DirectoryEntry(path))
                {
                    using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(de)
                    {
                        Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))"
                    })
                    {
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DisplayName");
                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

                        results = search.FindOne();

                        if (null != results)
                            _Path = results.Path;
                    };
                }
            }
        }


 using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry(_Path))
        {
            using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
            {
                return search.FindOne();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have the root in my original code. i removed it for security purposes.